# Exception on editing text in NSTableView

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstableview, cocoa-bindings

I have a nib containing a window and an array controller, and I have a subclass of NSWindowController that is set as the File's Owner of the nib.  The array controller has class name `NSMutableString`, and Editable is checked.  The window contains a cell-based NSTableView with a single column.  That table column's value is bound to the array controller (controller key "arrangedObjects", model key path empty).  The table column and its text field cell are set as Editable.

I load some strings into the array controller and display the dialog, and it looks right.  If I select a row and hit Enter, the row becomes editable as expected.  If I then edit the text and hit Enter again, an exception is thrown, with log messages indicating that an unrecognized selector `count` was sent to my window controller.  Why?

Here's what the backtrace looks like.

```
libobjc.A.dylib  objc_exception_throw
Foundation  -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forUndefinedKey:] + 285
Foundation  _NSSetUsingKeyValueSetter + 46
Foundation  -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 413
Foundation  -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKeyPath:] + 418
AppKit  -[NSArrayController _setMultipleValue:forKeyPath:atIndex:] + 332
AppKit  -[_NSControllerArrayProxy _setValue:forKeyPath:ofObjectAtIndex:] + 57
AppKit  -[NSBinder _setValue:forKeyPath:ofObject:mode:validateImmediately:raisesForNotApplicableKeys:error:] + 816
AppKit  -[NSBinder setValue:forBinding:atIndex:error:] + 327
AppKit  -[_NSValueBinderPlugin applyObjectValue:forBinding:operation:needToRunAlert:error:] + 412
AppKit  -[NSValueBinder _applyObjectValue:forBinding:canRecoverFromErrors:handleErrors:typeOfAlert:discardEditingCallback:otherCallback:callbackContextInfo:didRunAlert:] + 96
AppKit  -[NSValueBinder applyDisplayedValueHandleErrors:typeOfAlert:canRecoverFromErrors:discardEditingCallback:otherCallback:callbackContextInfo:didRunAlert:error:] + 643
AppKit  -[NSValueBinder _applyDisplayedValueIfHasUncommittedChangesWithHandleErrors:typeOfAlert:discardEditingCallback:otherCallback:callbackContextInfo:didRunAlert:error:] + 140
AppKit  -[NSValueBinder validateAndCommitValueInEditor:editingIsEnding:errorUserInterfaceHandled:] + 474
AppKit  -[_NSBindingAdaptor _validateAndCommitValueInEditor:editingIsEnding:errorUserInterfaceHandled:bindingAdaptor:] + 180
AppKit  -[_NSBindingAdaptor validateAndCommitValueInEditor:editingIsEnding:errorUserInterfaceHandled:] + 222
AppKit  -[NSTableView textShouldEndEditing:] + 388
```

Array controller connections: [image: Array controller connections]

---

I was able to get my window to work with the following changes:

1. Set the class name of the array controller to NSMutableDictionary.
2. Instead of adding mutable strings to the array controller, add mutable dictionaries, each having a single key "text".
3. On the table column binding, set the model key path to "text".

Here's a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30892315/binding-an-nstableview-to-an-array-of-strings-in-swift) in which the error message was less cryptic.  Maybe it's that he was using Swift and I'm not, maybe it's that I'm using a relatively old version of Xcode (4.6.3).

Comment: Are any of the bindings of the array controller bound? Which, and to what? Likewise, are any of its outlets set? My guess is that the array controller's content is connected to the window controller using one of those mechanisms. It's trying to set the edited string through the window controller.

Comment: @KenThomases, no, the array controller does not have any bindings bound or outlets set, see added image.